# Using reflection to load MemberData in XUnit test

Tags: .net, .net-core, xunit, system.reflection

**Scenario:** I have two enums, one called Area and another called Permission, they're used to set up operational authorization. I loop through them and end up with policies that have a name thats structured like AreaPermission. I then have a separate class full of string constants that are used in the auth attribute on a controller `[Authorize(Policy = MyClass.PolicyName)]`

**Desired Result:** I want a unit test that goes through all the properties on the class of constants, and calls the method that gets all the policy names for authorization policy DI service registration. So that in the future, if a dev adds a permission value or area value then the unit test will pick up if the string constant has not been created.

**Current result:** I am currently getting a no data result:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : No data found for OperationPoliciesTest.PoliciesExistInRegistrationMethod
  Exception doesn't have a stacktrace
```

TestData class:

```
public class OperationalPoliciesTestData  : IEnumerable<object[]>
    {
        public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var t = typeof(OperationPolicies);
            var props = t.GetProperties();

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                yield return new object[] {prop.Name};
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Test class:

```
public class OperationPoliciesTest
    {
        private readonly List<string> _registeredPolicies;

        public OperationPoliciesTest()
        {
            var policies =
                OperationalRequirementRegister.GetAllOperationalPolicyNames();

            _registeredPolicies = new List<string>(policies.Keys);
        }


        [Theory]
        [ClassData(typeof(OperationalPoliciesTestData))]
        public void PoliciesExistInRegistrationMethod(string policyName)
        {
            Assert.NotEmpty(_registeredPolicies);
            Assert.NotNull(policyName);
            Assert.Contains(policyName, _registeredPolicies);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on if I am missing something?